# How to display only the excerpt in the blog/posts page with Gutenberg?

Tags: excerpt, block-editor, blog-page

I'm building a custom child theme using the [Twenty Nineteen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentynineteen/) default WordPress theme as the parent.

I added some text in the excerpt section available in the Editor as follows:

[image]

But the full content of each post is displayed on the blog/posts page instead of just the excerpt.

---

What is the proper way of adding/using excerpts in the new Gutenberg editor?

Comment: Are you trying to display only the excerpt on the front-end or in Gutenberg itself?

Comment: @phatskat In the front-end blog page.

Comment: One more question - is this for single pages or the blog post list page? Also, which theme are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom page for this. For reference, we can modify the default (twentynineteen) post content block. Depending on your theme, you may need to modify `single.php`, or a content block included from there. In the `twentynineteen` theme, we can see this on line `24`:

```php
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'single' );
```

Following that, we can look into `template-parts/content/content-single.php` at line `23`:

```php
 23         the_content(
 24             sprintf(
 25                 wp_kses(
 26                     /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
 27                     __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentynineteen' ),
 28                     array(
 29                         'span' => array(
 30                             'class' => array(),
 31                         ),
 32                     )
 33                 ),
 34                 get_the_title()
 35             )
 36         );
 37
```

So, you could replace this call to `the_content` with something like this:

```php
the_excerpt(); // Echo the excerpt directly.
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); // Store the excerpt in $excerpt.

// Retrieve the "raw" exceprt - this has not passed any filters etc,
// and instead comes directly from the database.
$post = get_post();
echo $post->post_excerpt;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `twentynineteen` front page is controlled by the file `/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/index.php`. It contains the code

```
while (have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  get_template_part('template-parts/content/content');
}
```

This code applies the template from the **.php** file in `template-parts/content/content.php`. (Note `template-parts/content` is a sub-directory of the theme directory) Change `content` to `content-excerpt` as follows

```
while (have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  get_template_part('template-parts/content/content-excerpt');
}
```

Now the **.php** file `template-parts/content/content-excerpt.php` is loaded instead, which is what you want

Answer (score 0):

you need modify your template, in your PHP change `the_content()`  to `the_excerpt()`

This php functions print the content and the excerpt respectively